# android start Dropbox activity

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox

I need to access Dropbox folders from my android app, select a file and open it in my app.
After having thought over integrating Dropbox library into my android app, I decided to make it much easier. My idea is to have a "Launch Dropbox" button which will just launch normal Dropbox application. And then, using intent-filters, I catch a file selected and open it in my app.

The question is: how do I launch Dropbox from my app? I guess I have to construct some intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.dropbox???", ????));
startActivity(intent);
```

What should there be instead of '???'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just looked the package name of dropbox application from my phone. This is what I use for these kind of operations.

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```